# Why NSAttributedString is not inherited with NSString ? NSAttributedString has parent Class as NSObject Why?

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsattributedstring

Why is `NSAttributedString` not inherited with `NSString` ? `NSAttributedString` has parent Class as `NSObject` Why?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to be a subclass of `NSString`? This class modifies the text so far that correlation between the `NSString` and `NSAttributedString` is close to comparing `NSString` and `UILabel`.

Although quite a few methods on the string can be overridden on attributed string such as length, is empty, substrings... But many of them may not. And it gets even worse when attributed string is inserted into other methods:

For instance string size with font is completely different for attributed string since it may hold information of font internally. The drawing of one or the other is completely different...

And can you imagine sending an attributed string as a string to some other data structures. For instance unknowingly packing attributed string into some JSON data or into database. Sure it may return the same value as `NSString` when being serialized but truthfully it makes more sense to serialize into some form of XML or HTML. The reason for that is so you can actually save it somewhere for reuse with all its data.

Anyway, it would not be correct to subclass a `NSString` to `NSAttributedString` because the functionality and data structures of the two is simply too different. You may look at if from a drawing perspective where I guess both could have the same superclass as `DrawableText` or something. But everything beyond that makes no sense at all. For instance if you compared two attributed string where their text is same but have different attributes would you say these are the same? I would say NO for most cases. `if !previousString.isEqual(newString) self.hasChanges = true` for invalidation would need to differ with its attributes. But doing a subscript like `dictionary[myMutableString]` should not include the attributes at all.

You might think "Why would someone use an attributed string as a key?". These things happen by mistake. You have a textfield and someone makes it a bit nicer by using an attributed string on it so `myTextField.text = myAttributedString` would work if attributed string was subclassed. But then `myTextField.text` is still defined as a normal string. So `dictionary[myTextField.text]` looks completely correct.